# How to return the system date by clicking a button using a JavaScript function?

Tags: javascript, html

I wanted to show the system date after clicking the button, but after clicking the button it shows nothing. I have just started JavaScript and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```js
function dateFunc() {
   return this.innerHTML = Date();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="dateFunc()">The time is?</button>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to pass `this` to the function so that you can refer that inside the function:

```js
function dateFunc(thatBtn) {
   return thatBtn.innerHTML = Date();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="dateFunc(this)">The time is?</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is in this line:

```
return this.innerHTML=Date();
```

because `this` is just a **reference** which points to `window` object.

Use `DOM` manipulation instead.

```js
function dateFunc() {
   return document.getElementById('result').innerHTML=Date();
}
```

```html
<button onclick="dateFunc()">The time is?</button>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: [I'm not sure using `document.write` is a very good idea..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/802854/why-is-document-write-considered-a-bad-practice)

Comment: @ChiragRavindra, he don't say that we wants to replace the text for button.

Comment: i used document.write and it is working. So i wanted to try something like this which didn't involve document.write

Answer (score 0):

Within `dateFunc()`, `this` is the window, which has no attribute `innerHTML`.

You could define an additional element to display the time and get that in `dateFunc()` via `documnet.getElementById()`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>

    <button onclick="dateFunc()">The time is?</button>
    <div id="display"></div>

    <script>
        function dateFunc() {
            document.getElementById("display").innerHTML=Date();
        }
    </script>

    </body>
</html>
```